# How to extract all uppercase row to a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which looks like this

| Name | Index1 | Index2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 67 | 70 |
| Aaa | 55 | 80 |
| Abb | 32 | 20 |
| BBB | 84 | 45 |
| Baa | 80 | 70 |
| Bbb | 13 | 40 |

where some rows have names with all `uppercase` and some with `lowercase`. How can i create another dataframe with only the uppercase rows

expected output will be :

| Name | Index1 | Index2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 67 | 70 |
| BBB | 84 | 45 |

Comment: Use str.upper() If it matches with original string, Then it is uppercase.

Comment: The description in the title and the provided output do not really match

Comment: haha ya sorry, I initially wanted to ask a different question and forgot to change the title after changing the description. @mozway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isupper` from pandas:

```
df = df.loc[df["Name"].str.isupper(), :]
```

Answer (score 0):

same as above, without using `loc`

```py
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(['AAA','Aaa','BBB','Bbb'],columns=['test'])
>>> df[df.test.str.isupper()==True]
  test
0  AAA
2  BBB
```